# What is "instr_index" in assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

The jump instruction is coded as:

0000 10|instr_index

So what is "instr_index" in this case?
I have to code it on the paper but I just dont know how I fill the section.

Comment: Jodel Tipp ;-) https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-17/ass17_5.html

Comment: This is explained fairly clearly in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.

Comment: I am using the the book already but its not that clearly. I understand every other code but just dont get what instr_index is

Comment: _"The low 28 bits of the target address is the `instr_index` field shifted left 2 bits. The remaining upper bits are the corresponding bits of the address of the instruction in the delay slot (not the branch itself)."_  What is not clear about that?